# Putting hyper links into a script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dom-events

I don't know what exactly is the problem here, but I need to make the PhoneNumber, Website and Email into hyper links and I don't really know where to start.

I tried something before using the anchor tag, but it didn't work.  The info is stored on my SQL table and it is being accessed by a PHP script that allows this script to use the data, just need to make the necessary links.

```
function geo() {
    var id = $.QueryString("id"),
        id = (!id) ? "null" : id; // Passing the value null to string
    var loadUrl = 'http://localhost/test/detail.php';
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/test/detail.php?id=' + id, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            if (val.Image != "" && val.Image != null) {
                $('#placePic').attr('src', 'images/' + val.Image);
            } else {
                $('#placePic').attr('src', 'images/default_image2.jpg');
            }
            if (val.Name != "" && val.Name != null) {
                $('#placeName').text(val.Name);
            }
            $("#list_All").html("");
            if (val.PhoneNumber != "" && val.PhoneNumber != null) {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Phone Number :</h3>" + val.PhoneNumber + "</li>");
            } else {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Phone Number :</h3>No Data Found</li>");
            }
            if (val.Address != "" && val.Address != null) {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Address :</h3>" + val.Address + "</li>");
            } else {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Address :</h3>No Data Found</li>");
            }
            if (val.Email != "" && val.Email != null) {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Email ID :</h3>" + val.Email + "</li>");
            } else {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Email ID :</h3>No Data Found</li>");
            }
            if (val.Website != "" && val.Website != null) {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Website :</h3>" + val.Website + "</li>");
            } else {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Website :</h3>No Data Found</li>");
            }
            $("#pom_btn").attr("href", "http://localhost/test/on_map.html?id=" + val.userId + "&lat=" + val.Lat + "&lon=" + val.Lon);
        });
    });
}
window.onload = function () {
    geo();
}
```

Comment: `"<a href='"+val.Website+"'>Link</a>"`?

Comment: Thanks Rocket it works, i did the same thing, only i left out the quotes silly mistake, thanks alot! but i'm lost on one thing though and its this eg: <a href='"mailto:+val.Email+"'>"+val.Email+"</a> is this valid or not

Comment: `"<a href='mailto:"+val.Email+"'>"+val.Email+"</a>"` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function geo() {
    var id = $.QueryString("id"),
        id = (!id) ? "null" : id; // Passing the value null to string
    var loadUrl = 'http://localhost/test/detail.php';
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/test/detail.php?id=' + id, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            if (val.Image != "" && val.Image != null) {
                $('#placePic').attr('src', 'images/' + val.Image);
            } else {
                $('#placePic').attr('src', 'images/default_image2.jpg');
            }
            if (val.Name != "" && val.Name != null) {
                $('#placeName').text(val.Name);
            }
            $("#list_All").html("");
            if (val.PhoneNumber != "" && val.PhoneNumber != null) {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Phone Number :</h3>" + 
                    "<a href='tel:" + val.PhoneNumber + "'>" + val.PhoneNumber + "</a></li>");
            } else {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Phone Number :</h3>No Data Found</li>");
            }
            if (val.Address != "" && val.Address != null) {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Address :</h3>" + val.Address + "</li>");
            } else {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Address :</h3>No Data Found</li>");
            }
            if (val.Email != "" && val.Email != null) {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Email ID :</h3>" 
                    "<a href='mailto:" + val.Email + "'>" + val.Email + "</a></li>");
            } else {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Email ID :</h3>No Data Found</li>");
            }
            if (val.Website != "" && val.Website != null) {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Website :</h3>" + 
                    "<a href='" + ((val.Website.indexOf("http")!=0)?"http://":"") + val.Website +
                    "'>" + val.Website + "</a></li>");
            } else {
                $("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Website :</h3>No Data Found</li>");
            }
            $("#pom_btn").attr("href", "http://localhost/test/on_map.html?id=" + val.userId + "&lat=" + val.Lat + "&lon=" + val.Lon);
        });
    });
}
window.onload = function () {
    geo();
}
```

For the website link, you'll need an "http://" or "https://" on the front of it. I did a simple test, but a more complete one might be needed depending on your case.

Comment: Every thing worked very well jwatts thank you very much, appreciate your help 100%!

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#list_All").append("<li><a href='" + val.Website + "'>Website</a></li>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just printing the address does not make it a hyperlink. You must have an anchor tag wrapped around it.

For example:

```
$("#list_All").append("<li><h3>Website :</h3><a href='" + val.Website + "'>" + val.Website + "</a></li>");
```